# How express you tie 2 strings in such a way that it has a loop?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Look at the picture above, when you tie 2 strings together, you create a complete knot like the last third picture. This kind of knot is very hard for you to untie them.

[image]

When I tie 2 strings together, I often form a loop like the above picture. This is easier for me to untie them.

Is it correct to say "**don't tie the 2 strings absolutely, tie them with a loop so that you can untie them easily**"?

**Note**:

I saw this example in Oxford Dictionary "**to tie your shoelaces in a bow**".

Similarly, can we say "**tie the 2 strings together in a bow**"?

However, a bow looks like **number 8**. But the second picture only shows 1 part of number 8 looking like "**o**" not "**a bow**"

Comment: if you wanted to tie two cords of different weight like that, a sheet bend is a better choice than a reef knot

Comment: Your picture looks like the yellow rope is tied into a *slipknot*, and the white shoelace is just threaded through it, not really part of the knot at all, so if I pulled the white one, it would just come out. Is that correct? are you just asking about the shape of the yellow rope, and not necessarily the white one?

Comment: @gotube, You are right! But, I never know how to tie. Just give it as an example. I just need to know how to say it in everyday ENglish.

Comment: @Tom Great. I've undeleted my answer and added a bit to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of loop is called a "bow".  Bows can be decorative or functional. Most well-known is the bow that is used to tie shoelaces together.

A knot with a bow that comes undone easily is said to be "slipped" so you could call your knot a "singly slipped reef knot".

But all this is for sailors and other people who use lots of knots. For talking to a child you could say "Tie it with a loop, so they can be undone easily", or "Tie it like this...(demonstrate)"

Comment: I saw this example in Oxford Dictionary "**to tie your shoelaces in a bow**". Similarly, can we say "**tie the 2 strings together in a bow**"? However, a bow looks like number 8. But my picture only shows 1 part of number 8 looking like "o"

Comment: Yes, hence a "singly slipped (or bowed)" knot.  A shoelace is classically tied with a doubly slipped reef knot.

Comment: A chatbot suggest saying "tie the shoelaces in a half-bow". A half-bow is a bow with just 1 loop. Can we say "in a half-bow" like that?

Comment: just as with my expression, this might be useful if you are talking to an expert in knots.  But if you are talking to a child, keep it simple.

Comment: To me, a bow always has two loops, and is designed to stay fastened until both are opened.

Answer (score 1):

## slipknot

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slipknot):

> **:** a knot that slips along the rope or line around which it is made
> **especially :** one made by tying an overhand knot around the standing part of a rope

[image: image of an orange rope tied into a slipknot]

A "bow" connects two separate strings together, each string tied with a slipknot around the other on top of an overhand knot.

[image]